How to save output without CR LF characters (Enter) during use redirection to text file in Batch Script?
When I redirect commands to save them in a text file, CR LF (Enter) is appended at the end of the line. I would like to save it in such a way that the result is only plain text. Is it possible without it?
@echo off
echo hello>> hello.txt
cd>>added_lines.txt
>output.txt (
echo one
)

In all three cases the content will look like this: hello[CR][LF], C:\Users\user\Desktop\directory[CR][LF], one[CR][LF].
How to save it so that there is no enter?

besides CRLF is a common and expected content of a "plain text" file: <nul set /p "=Hello "&<nul set /p "=World."

There are many not good coded programs which process the last line of a text file not correct if there is no line termination (carriage return and line-feed on Windows) at the end of the last line in the file. It is advisable that a Windows text file always ends with \r\n. But it is possible to redirected the prompt text of command set /P into a file which is output by SET always without a line ending character and define as input stream the device NUL resulting in SET not waiting for user input. Example: set /P "=Hello" 0<nul 1>>hello.txt appends just Hello to the file.
